# Increment a number for select group header sections per group

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a unique question that I am not sure is even possible.

I have a report that has several Group Headers per group.  What I would like to do is have select Group Headers (GH1a, GH1p, GH1w...) have an auto incremented number, which I will then turn into an roman numeral using roman(@function).  The numbering would be independent on the number of actual groups, only Group Headers. There could be one to 100,000 records (groups) returned to the report but for each record(group) the Group Headers within each group would have select Group Headers numbered the same

EX:

GROUP A

```
GH1a:  I
GH1b:  
GH1c:  II
GH1d:  III
GH1e:
GH1f:
GH1g:  IV
```

GROUP B

```
GH1a:  I
GH1b:  
GH1c:  II
GH1d:  III
GH1e:
GH1f:
GH1g:  IV
```

etc....

Any help would be appreciated.  I have tried to use a global variable x in both the report header and each GH that I want incremented using the following code:

in reportheader and/or GH1a //@iCountreset

```
    Global NumberVar iCount:=1;
```

in each GH that I want incremented //@iCounted

```
    Global Numbervar iCount;
    iCount:= iCount+1;
```

then a second one to romanize it //@RomanCount

```
    roman(@iCounted);
```

I currently have them hard coded but am trying to combine several rpt files into one where the only difference would be some GH sections would be suppressed and therefore not counted in the numbering.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//{@reset}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global Numbervar G1:=1;

//{@increment}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global Numbervar G1:=G1+1;

//{@roman}
Roman({@increment})
```

** edit **

Ryan's comment was correct.  My new approach uses subreports to increment a shared variable, which works.

Steps:

add {@reset} GH1a of 'main' report; suppress

```
//{@reset}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared Numbervar G1:=0;
```

create a subreport; place it in GH1b; add these formulae to it:

add to Details section; suppress:

```
//{@increment}
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared Numbervar G1:=G1+1;
```

add to Details section:

```
//{@roman}
Roman({@increment})
```

You will need to add this subreport to each section that requires a Roman-numeral calculation.  To make this process a little less painful, export the subreport ('save subreport as'), then reinsert it.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. I don't think CR will evaluate the same formula for each GH section if you place it in the report multiple times. It would end up printing "II" over and over.

Comment: You are right, Ryan.  The {@increment} function suffers that fatal flaw.

Comment: I see how that can work, but is there a way without subreports? I really hate being dependent on "outside" variables other than the result set.  Not being picky I'm just sure there is a cleaner way?